# http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list.xml not accessible

Tags: android

http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list.xml not accessible from browser and also from android SDK manager. Please help

Comment: remove old sdk, download new and try again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ecplise Goto->Help->Install New Software.
Put the URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ in Work With option.

You will get Developer Tools Option. Select Android Development tools. Install this.
Then goto Window->Android SDK Manager you can see all the packages listed. Select the one you want to install.

Answer (score 3):

The correct link is 
`https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml`

Comment: Thanks. But I want to add third party add-ons.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows XP:

I created many projects successfully. Problem came when i needed to update the sdk. I was shoked when i was unable to update. I did not have the option to set proxy as there was only one option available in the Tools menu i.e `Tools->Manage Add-On Sites`

I fixed this

Go to the android sdk installation path in my case it is `**D:\Program Files\android-sdk\tools**`

edit android.bat file and add `-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxyserver -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128  after %REMOTE_DEBUG%`

Run the sdk manager. On the SDK Manager UI Go to Tools -> Options -> Set the same proxy server and port .

Check Force `https://`

This solution works for me.

Answer (score 1):

thanks friend i had the same problem before i did the below sections and is my slution:
 in sdk manager >>>tools>>>options>> mark the two box in the bottom of window.wich changes the proxy in right way .then reload the sdk manager from file .

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you could do is to go to: **TOOLS > OPTIONS**.
Then, in the **other** section (the bottom) select
**Force https://... to be fetched using http://**
Then Close it. This should solve.

Answer (score 0):

Run the sdk manager. On the SDK Manager UI Go to Tools -> Options -> Set the same proxy server and port .

Check Force https://

leave everything else the same - worked for me!